# How do I get the ROI of both eyes of a face

Tags: python, opencv, roi, haar-classifier

I am currently trying to get the ROI of both eyes in a face. However, it is only returning the right eye. How do I get the ROI of both eyes like in a single frame?

```
for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h),(0,255,0), 2)
        faceROI = img[y:y+h,x:x+w]

        smile_rects = smile_cascade.detectMultiScale(faceROI, scaleFactor=1.1, minNeighbors=10, minSize=(15, 15), flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE)
        eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(faceROI)
        
        for (x2, y2, w2, h2) in eyes:
            ptA = (x + x2, y + y2)
            ptB = (x + x2 + w2, y + y2 + h2)
            cv2.rectangle(img, ptA, ptB, (0, 0, 255), 2)
            eyeROI = faceROI[y2:y2+h2,x2:x2+w2]
cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.imshow('EyeROI', eyeROI)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Look carefully at your code. What happens to `eyeROI` on every loop iteration? When are you actually `imshow`ing this image?

Comment: I tried showing the ROI image inside the for loop, however the output is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To crop each eye you need to display the image in the loop, and they need to have a different name or else the last one will always overwrite. See code below on a fictional person.

```
img = cv2.imread('./not_a_real_person.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)

for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h),(0,255,0), 2)
    faceROI = img[y:y+h,x:x+w]

    eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(faceROI)
    eye_count = 1
    for (x2, y2, w2, h2) in eyes:
        ptA = (x + x2, y + y2)
        ptB = (x + x2 + w2, y + y2 + h2)
        cv2.rectangle(img, ptA, ptB, (0, 0, 255), 2)
        eyeROI = faceROI[y2:y2+h2,x2:x2+w2]
        cv2.imshow('eye %d'%eye_count, eyeROI)
        eye_count+=1

cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: Example]

Without the face detection:

```
img = cv2.imread('./not_a_real_person_cropped.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray)
eye_count = 1
for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes:
    cv2.rectangle(img,(ex,ey),(ex+ew,ey+eh),(0,255,0),2)
    eyeROI = img[ey:ey+eh,ex:ex+ew]
    cv2.imshow('eye_%d'%eye_count, eyeROI)
    eye_count+=1
```

[image: Example2]

Comment: Ohh thanks @Tiphel ! I am wondering if I can use that without the need of using the face_cascade. Like for example, I have a cropped face image. Does detecting the face is still relevant? However, if I am going to remove the face_cascade, what would be the structure of the code since the eye detection is inside the for loop of the face detect.

Comment: Yes you can apply the eye detection straight away, the face detection isn't necessary, it would simply restrict the search area and limit false positives. But if your image is already cropped around the face there is no need for it. In the code remove the face loop and apply the eye to the main image.

Comment: I see, but how are we going to get the x, y, w, and h values if we will be removing the for loop of the face @Tiphel ?

Comment: It's pretty straight forward, I added the code in my answer edit.